# Unable to Query Linked Server

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linked-server, openquery

I am unable to query a Linked Oracle server through C# code using OpenQuery I can however query the server from Sql Server itself, using either a 4 part name or OpenQuery. I get the following error when using code:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LinkedServer" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.  Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LinkedServer".     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()     at TerminateEmployeeForm.FormCode.FormEvents_Loading(Object sender, LoadingEventArgs e)

My code look like the following:

```
    testCommand = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,'SELECT * FROM HR.REGION')";

     SqlCommand cmdTest = new SqlCommand();

    cmdTest.Connection = conn1;
            cmdTest.CommandText = testCommand;
            cmdTest.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    conn1.Open();

    SqlDataReader testdr = cmdTest.ExecuteReader();

    string values = null;

            if (testdr.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (testdr.Read())
                {
                    values = values + testdr["REGION_FIELD"].ToString();

                }
            }
```

Comment: It turns out this was a permissions issue. The infopath forms could not access the data in the DB. I would have thought that the SQL services service account would work as normal but it did not. Instead I created a SQL login and then granted it permissions on the SQL DB specified in the connection string as well as adding the user name and password to the connection string.